# import excel to sql database

Tags: asp.net

I am not programmer but try to do something study from Internet. Here
I try to  import excel data to sql database with asp.net c#. I get a
concept from Internet about this but i get a error message like this
"Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'valid' takes
1 arguments" My code details are below:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Loan History File Format :</td>
             <td><input type="button" value="Download" onclick='location.href = "CardDefaulterTemplete.xlsx#TableName"'/></td>
            <td rowspan="2">Before upload data, you must follow this file format. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" Visibl="False"/></td>
           <td> <asp:Button ID="btnCardDefaulter" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
        onclick="btnCardDefaulter_Click"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Excel" 
        onclick="btnExcel_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:Label>

</div>
```

c# Code"

```
protected string valid(SqlDataReader myreader, int stval)//if any columns are found null then they are replaced by zero
    {
        object val = myreader[stval];
        if (val != DBNull.Value)
            return val.ToString();
        else
            return Convert.ToString(0);
    }

    public void insertdataintosql(string LHAcNo, string LhAcName, int LHIntRate, string LHDrawingPower, int LHtotalDisbAmt
                            , int LHEMI, string LHExpiryDate, string LHSanctionDate, string LHDisbDate, int LHOutstandingAmt, int LHPaidAmt
                            , int LHLastMonthPaid, string LHStatus, string LhCLStatus)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string str = @"insert TblLoanHistory (LHAcNo
                        ,LhAcName
                        ,LHIntRate
                        ,LHDrawingPower
                        ,LHtotalDisbAmt
                        ,LHEMI
                        ,LHExpiryDate
                        ,LHSanctionDate
                        ,LHDisbDate
                        ,LHOutstandingAmt
                        ,LHPaidAmt
                        ,LHLastMonthPaid
                        ,LHStatus
                        ,LhCLStatus) values(@LHAcNo
                        ,@LhAcName
                        ,@LHIntRate
                        ,@LHDrawingPower
                        ,@LHtotalDisbAmt
                        ,@LHEMI
                        ,@LHExpiryDate
                        ,@LHSanctionDate
                        ,@LHDisbDate
                        ,@LHOutstandingAmt
                        ,@LHPaidAmt
                        ,@LHLastMonthPaid
                        ,@LHStatus
                        ,@LhCLStatus)";

           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn))
           {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHAcNo",LHAcNo);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LhAcName",LhAcName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHIntRate",LHIntRate);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHDrawingPower",LHDrawingPower);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHtotalDisbAmt",LHtotalDisbAmt);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHEMI",LHEMI);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHExpiryDate",LHExpiryDate);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHSanctionDate",LHSanctionDate);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHDisbDate",LHDisbDate);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHOutstandingAmt",LHOutstandingAmt);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHPaidAmt",LHPaidAmt);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHLastMonthPaid",LHLastMonthPaid);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LHStatus",LHStatus);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LhCLStatu",LhCLStatus);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
                conn.Close();
        }
    }


    protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon"].ConnectionString))

        try
        {
            string tmpPath = string.Format(@"{0}{1}.xlsx", (@"e:\temp\"), DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
            if (File.Exists(tmpPath)) File.Delete(tmpPath);
            if (fileUpload1.HasFile)
                fileUpload1.SaveAs(tmpPath);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(tmpPath);
            ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(file);
            var excelApp = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets["main_info"];

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select LHAcNo, LhAcName, LHIntRate, LHDrawingPower, LHtotalDisbAmt, LHEMI, LHExpiryDate, LHSanctionDate, LHDisbDate, LHOutstandingAmt, LHPaidAmt, LHLastMonthPaid, LHStatus, LhCLStatus from [Template$]", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    string Call_LHAcNo = "";
                    string Call_LhAcName = "";
                    int Call_LHIntRate = 0;
                    string Call_LHDrawingPower = "";
                    int Call_LHtotalDisbAmt = 0;
                    int Call_LHEMI = 0;
                    string Call_LHExpiryDate = "";
                    string Call_LHSanctionDate = "";
                    string Call_LHDisbDate = "";
                    int Call_LHOutstandingAmt =0;
                    int Call_LHPaidAmt =0;
                    int Call_LHLastMonthPaid = 0;
                    string Call_LHStatus = "";
                    string Call_LhCLStats = "";
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Call_LHAcNo = valid(dr[1]); 
                        Call_LhAcName = valid(dr[2]);
                        Call_LHIntRate = valid(dr[3]);
                        Call_LHDrawingPower = valid(dr[4]);
                        Call_LHtotalDisbAmt = valid(dr[5]);
                        Call_LHEMI = valid(dr[6]);
                        Call_LHExpiryDate = valid(dr[7]);
                        Call_LHSanctionDate = valid(dr[8]);
                        Call_LHDisbDate = valid(dr[9]);
                        Call_LHOutstandingAmt = valid(dr[10]);
                        Call_LHPaidAmt = valid(dr[11]);
                        Call_LHLastMonthPaid = valid(dr[12]);
                        Call_LHStatus = valid(dr[13]);
                        Call_LhCLStats = valid(dr[14]);

                        insertdataintosql(Call_LHAcNo,
                            Call_LhAcName,
                            Call_LHIntRate,
                            Call_LHDrawingPower,
                            Call_LHtotalDisbAmt,
                            Call_LHEMI,
                            Call_LHExpiryDate,
                            Call_LHSanctionDate,
                            Call_LHDisbDate,
                            Call_LHOutstandingAmt,
                            Call_LHPaidAmt,
                            Call_LHLastMonthPaid,
                            Call_LHStatus,
                            Call_LhCLStats);
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DataException ee)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = ee.Message;
            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        finally
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Data Inserted Sucessfully";
            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

I have confusion about  "`protected string valid(SqlDataReader
myreader, int stval)`" and under "`protected void btnExcel_Click(object
sender, EventArgs e)`" import date from excel and processing while
loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling method valid() with one argument in some where in you code. please make sure that you are passing two parameters to valid() function.

In you code you are calling valid function like this.

```
Call_LHAcNo = valid(dr[1]);
```

But in valid function is accepting two arguments valid(SqlDataReader myreader, int stval)

You need to provide two argument to function or change your function to one argument.

Comment: I can't understand that. if u don't mind pls solve my problem.